# Guardar carateres do ecra

Tags: assembly

Boa tarde, quero guardar carateres do ecra num ficheiro. O tamanho é 20 linhas e 40 colunas. Desenvolvi código, mas ele só está a guardar 14 linhas. Alguém me consegue ajudar?

Código:

```
mov bx,0
mov si,0
mov ax,0
mov di,si
mov cx, 80
lab_ciclo: 
       mov al, es:[bx]
       mov buffer[si], al
       inc si
       add bx,2
    loop lab_ciclo
       add di,82
       mov si,di
       mov cx,82
       cmp si, 2050
       jne lab_ciclo
```